# How to have multi select autocompletion in wicket?

Tags: javascript, wicket

I have a requirement where I need the autocomplete feature of textfield & allow multiple selection. I searched the net for resources [like wicket stuff and [this](http://osdir.com/ml/java-wicket-user/2008-06/msg00605.html) ] but could not find any.

My Question -

1) Does wicket provide any component of this kind?

2) What work around can I have to accomplish this?

3) Can we use jquery in wicket?

I am having legacy code using wicket 1.4.18 & its hard to upgrade to the latest wicket due to time constraints.

Appreciate all your inputs.

Comment: Conversion from wicket 1.4 to wicket 6 took us 1 man day. In our example it was not so hard. Mostly name refactorings. It will get harder if you for example modified onclick javascript on components, the parts where wicket has changed the most - javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the exact same problem as you a while back....At that point we had a custom component that  did exactly what you need (multi-seclect-autocomplete). The component used a lot of Javascript and sadly did not perform the same on all browsers.
After some research I found [Select2-Wicket](https://github.com/ivaynberg/wicket-select2) witch is the wicket implementation of [Select2 component](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/).This really solved all the problems...it is genius. 
The only problem you have regarding this component is that it does not have 1.4 wicket support and you will have to either port it to 1.4 or make the switch at least to 1.5(that is what I did).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will try this out & post the findings here

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a multichoice in a [`ModalWindow`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.html) with a `TextField` and a `ListView` with the values filtered by the TextField input and selectable by `Checkbox`es.

ModalWindow and all other components are in Wicket 1.4. You have custom component which you can fully control. You can make it work and look like you want. You are not depending on an external component (i mean Select2).

The advantage of Select2 is the much better UX. However control is limited. It's hard to change it's appearance, it might not fit into your App. Not all js events from the orginal component are exposed and you might evolve into some complex scenario where you will encounter the limits of (Wicket)Select2. It is ok for basic tasks.